# Calling MongoDB from Flask python3 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web-applications, chat, ubuntu-22.04

Following is the header of 'home.py' of a chat web app I am building using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect  
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import os
import time
import json
import pymongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'any random string'

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
user_db = myclient["authentication"]
user_table = user_db["user_info"]
```

Later the code has five lines:

```
print("0")
print(req)
print(type(user_table))
query = user_table.find({'uid':req['uid']})     
print(query)
print('1')
```

The output is:

```
0
{'uid': '', 'email': '', 'password': ''}
<class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f62f684f700>
1
```

followed by flask error.

Kindly help.

I am stuck at 40 minutes 04 seconds of chapter 2 of this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5Tf33vPUXBJmeZmZsYH3Yyt51Rk6S7Pd).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` returns an iterable cursor, so either do:

```
query = user_table.find({'uid':req['uid']})     
for item in query:
    print(item)
```

or

```
query = user_table.find({'uid':req['uid']})     
print(list(query))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Apparently, this code is not functional, so I am moving to another.